# How can I use different array based on the device language?

Tags: ios, arrays, iphone, swift, translate

In my app I have 3 array, one for the base language (English) and other two for the localization. Can I select a specific array based on the language set on users device? For example, if the device is set to use German language I want to take the phrases translated in German.

This are the variables that I create

```
var enQuotes:[String] = []
var itQuotes:[String] = []
var deQuotes:[String] = []
```

and this are the method to get the quotes from the file

```
enQuotes = quotes_en.getEnQuotes()
itQuotes = quotes_it.getItQuotes()
deQuotes = quotes_de.getDeQuotes()
```

and this is the code that I use to set random phrases

```
override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if let firstTouch = touches.first {
        let hitView = self.view.hitTest(firstTouch.location(in: self.view), with: event)

        if hitView === backgroundView {

            let randomArray = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(enQuotes.count)))
            phraseLbl.text = (enQuotes[randomArray])

            print("touch is inside")

        } else {
            print("touch is outside")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What about using `LocalizedString()`. You set the key/values for each quotes, and then you construct one single array?

Answer (score 0):

Store the quotes as a localized property list resource "Quotes.plist" in the app. As an example, the english version would look like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
    <string>First Quote</string>
    <string>Second Quote</string>
    <string>Third Quote</string>
</array>
</plist>
```

Add localizations for every supported language.

At runtime, locate the property list with the `Bundle.url(forResource:withExtension:)` method, this will automatically pick
the right version according to the user's language setting.
Then read the data and de-serialize it into a an array of strings:

```
let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Quotes", withExtension: "plist")!
let data = try! Data(contentsOf: url)
let quotes = try! PropertyListDecoder().decode([String].self, from: data)
```

(The forced unwrapping and forced trys are acceptable here, because any
failure would indicate a *programming error* which needs to be fixed.)